# Ruby on rails, Jquery autocomplete not showing names correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have an Order model and a Customer model such that the Order belongs_to Customer. I'm using the [rails-jquery-autocomplete gem](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) and I'm trying to build a form with a belongs_to association.  I managed to get the Customer to save correctly from the order side, but now if you look at the form during editing it shows this.

[image]

I would love for it to show the customer name. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

This is the view for that section of the form.

```
.panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      =f.label :customer
    .panel-body
      =f.autocomplete_field :customer, :autocomplete_customer_name, placeholder: 'Customer', id_element: "#customer_id"
      =f.hidden_field :customer_id, id:"customer_id"
      =link_to "new customer", new_customer_path, class: "new_customer_link"
```

This is the controller for the form:

```
class OrderssController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :customer, :name
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle]
...

def rfq_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :due, :ship_date, :is_budgetary, :notes, :end_user, :application, :mandatory_due_date, :tag_list)
```

and here are the relevant models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :valves, :class_name => "Valve"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :valves, :allow_destroy => true
    belongs_to :customer

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    belongs_to :company
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't get this working "correctly" instead I added a customer_name attribute to the order. and changed

```
=f.autocomplete_field :customer, :autocomplete_customer_name, placeholder: 'Customer', id_element: "#customer_id"
```

to

```
=f.autocomplete_field :customer_name, :autocomplete_customer_name, placeholder: 'Customer', id_element: "#customer_id"
```

which is unfortunate but it had the desired result.